# Is there a way for RestAPI deployed using App Engine to call a Flask app deployed using Compute Engine? (Google Cloud Platform)

Tags: express, flask, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to create an overall architecture for Google Cloud Platform which has a machine learning model using Flask that is deployed with Compute Engine, and a RestAPI deployed using App Engine which will call the earlier Flask app in the code.

I've been stuck for a while trying to make this API work, this index.js that I have requires connection to the flask app which I wrote like below:

```
const getData = async (body) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const requestOptions = {
        url: 'http://34.101.174.174:5000/api/flask',
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          offset: 20
        }
      };
  
      console.log('Before making the request');
      axios(requestOptions)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('Response body:', response.data);
          resolve(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error:', error);
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  };
```

When I run the API locally and test one of the Get API that calls the flask app using Postman, it works just fine. However, when I test it using the deployed App Engine url, it returns a Bad Request.

I did check the logs and it says: [Server] Access denied for user 'sa'@'45.93.201.68' (using password: YES)". I have never configured a user like above for MySQL. I have also made sure to provide sufficient permission in terms of service account and firewall configuration for the App Engine and Compute Engine instance.

Comment: Are you saying that when your GAE App running in Production calls the API which you've temporarily hosted locally, it works?